# Locale stops working after a while in rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

We're having an issue with locales on heroku. At first, the locales are working *perfectly*, but after a while the dynos stops serving anything but english even though swedish is our default locale. The issue is always resolved by restarting our dynos - not once but **twice**. We've tried to find solutions for this for some time but we've failed to find anything to do about it.

Any ideas?

We load the locale files super vanilla, i.e:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :sv
config.i18n.available_locales = [:sv, :en]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to us missing a few translation files in one of our languages. If you're experiencing the same issue, make sure that ALL translation files present and that all the translated strings are there for every language.